# SML/NJ run external commands/scripts

Tags: shell, sml, smlnj

Is it possible to run bash shell commands via SML/NJ?

In Python, it would be using modules like [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

I am hoping to use `diff fileA fileB` in an sml script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could use `system` function in [`OS.Process`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/os-process.html) structure.

```
OS.Process.system "diff fileA fileB";
```